# How to use a initialization list for Dialog that is added to MFC Doc/Frame project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

I added a extra Dialog (TestDialog) in a MFC doc/frame peoject (Single doc, MFC, VC++2010 project) and the TestDialog.h file shows that

```
class CTestDialog : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

public:
    CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

virtual ~CTestDialog();
}
```

Then I added the following varaible that I will use in the TestDialog.h file
public:

```
BOOL        m_x;          
long        m_Type
```

TestDialog.cpp file shows

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , testdlg(0)
{
}

CTestDialog::~CTestDialog()
{
}
```

Now I have a use a initilization list that is working for frame/doc file ( declared in ..Doc.cpp file
and corresponding variable decared in .h file and it works perfectly. But whenever I want to decare same thing in dialog although the varaible are accessible from dialog box, but I didnt able to initialize the variable values. So ..

I want to add a initialization list for m_x and m_Type in TestDialog.cpp file

```
 :
    m_x(FALSE)
    m_Type(0)
```

I tried to add like below

```
CTestDialog::~CTestDialog():
m_x(FALSE)
m_Type(0)
{
}
```

or

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
         :m_x(FALSE),m_Type(0)
    : CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , testdlg(0)
{
}
```

But none of them worked and the compiler compain that initiazation list is only declarable in constructor. How can I decalre a initization list for this dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog already has an initialization list, you just add your changes like this:

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , testdlg(0)
    , m_x(FALSE)
    , m_Type(0)
{
}
```

The general syntax is:

```
CSomeClass::CSomeClass() : m_var1(1), m_var2(2), m_var3(3)
{
}
```

Where your initializer list follows the definition of the constructor after a `:` and the variables names - `m_var1` etc. in this example - are separated by commas and have the initial values in brackets. As with the dialog, you can also include base class constructors in the initialisation list.

The layout in the dialog source code just puts each variable on a new line.